# Creating a unique ID for an application on runtime

Tags: c++, winapi

This seems to work on some version of windows and acts weird on others. This is unstable and redundant.

How can I improve this in a way that it has the same expected behavior through every windows version starting from Windows XP to 10.

When the application starts it checks if a unique ID already exists. If it does, it uses that unique ID for some other task. If it does not, then it creates a unique ID and then uses it for some other task.

To note, this is the definition of `buf` and `len`:

```
unsigned char *buf, size_t len,
```

Here is the code that needs reviewing:

```
    HKEY hKey = nullptr;
    UUID uuid;
    DWORD dwDisp;
    DWORD dwUUIDSize = sizeof(uuid);
    unsigned char dwUUID[16];

    std::vector<unsigned char> login_buf(len + dwUUIDSize);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) login_buf[i] = buf[i];

    if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Mirinae\\Khan_LI"), 0, NULL, 0, KEY_WRITE | KEY_READ, NULL, &hKey, &dwDisp) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        if (dwDisp == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY) 
        {
            UuidCreate(&uuid);

            dwUUID[0] = (uuid.Data1 >> 0) & 0xFF;
            dwUUID[1] = (uuid.Data1 >> 8) & 0xFF;
            dwUUID[2] = (uuid.Data1 >> 16) & 0xFF;
            dwUUID[3] = (uuid.Data1 >> 24) & 0xFF;
            dwUUID[4] = (uuid.Data2 >> 0) & 0xFF;
            dwUUID[5] = (uuid.Data2 >> 8) & 0xFF;
            dwUUID[6] = (uuid.Data3 >> 0) & 0xFF;
            dwUUID[7] = (uuid.Data3 >> 8) & 0xFF;
            dwUUID[8] = uuid.Data4[0];
            dwUUID[9] = uuid.Data4[1];
            dwUUID[10] = uuid.Data4[2];
            dwUUID[11] = uuid.Data4[3];
            dwUUID[12] = uuid.Data4[4];
            dwUUID[13] = uuid.Data4[5];
            dwUUID[14] = uuid.Data4[6];
            dwUUID[15] = uuid.Data4[7];

            RegSetValueEx(hKey, TEXT("keyinfo"), 0, REG_BINARY, (LPBYTE)dwUUID, dwUUIDSize);

            for (size_t i = 0; i < dwUUIDSize; i++) login_buf.push_back(dwUUID[i]);
        }
        else {
            if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, TEXT("keyinfo"), 0, 0, (LPBYTE)dwUUID, &dwUUIDSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < dwUUIDSize; i++) login_buf.push_back(dwUUID[i]);
            }
            else {
                UuidCreate(&uuid);

                dwUUID[0] = (uuid.Data1 >> 0) & 0xFF;
                dwUUID[1] = (uuid.Data1 >> 8) & 0xFF;
                dwUUID[2] = (uuid.Data1 >> 16) & 0xFF;
                dwUUID[3] = (uuid.Data1 >> 24) & 0xFF;
                dwUUID[4] = (uuid.Data2 >> 0) & 0xFF;
                dwUUID[5] = (uuid.Data2 >> 8) & 0xFF;
                dwUUID[6] = (uuid.Data3 >> 0) & 0xFF;
                dwUUID[7] = (uuid.Data3 >> 8) & 0xFF;
                dwUUID[8] = uuid.Data4[0];
                dwUUID[9] = uuid.Data4[1];
                dwUUID[10] = uuid.Data4[2];
                dwUUID[11] = uuid.Data4[3];
                dwUUID[12] = uuid.Data4[4];
                dwUUID[13] = uuid.Data4[5];
                dwUUID[14] = uuid.Data4[6];
                dwUUID[15] = uuid.Data4[7];

                RegSetValueEx(hKey, TEXT("keyinfo"), 0, REG_BINARY, (LPBYTE)dwUUID, dwUUIDSize);

                for (size_t i = 0; i < dwUUIDSize; i++) login_buf.push_back(dwUUID[i]);
            }
        }

        RegCloseKey(hKey);

        // add username
        char strbuf[500];
        int strlen;

        char *cname = nullptr;
        size_t cnameLen = 0;
        _dupenv_s(&cname, &cnameLen, "COMPUTERNAME");
        char *uname = nullptr;
        size_t unameLen = 0;
        _dupenv_s(&uname, &unameLen, "USERNAME");

        // add os info
        if (IsWindowsXPOrGreater())       strlen = sprintf_s(strbuf, "%s|%s|WindowsXP", cname, uname);
        if (IsWindowsXPSP1OrGreater())    strlen = sprintf_s(strbuf, "%s|%s|WindowsXP-SP1", cname, uname);
        if (IsWindowsXPSP2OrGreater())    strlen = sprintf_s(strbuf, "%s|%s|WindowsXP-SP2", cname, uname);
        if (IsWindowsXPSP3OrGreater())    strlen = sprintf_s(strbuf, "%s|%s|WindowsXP-SP3", cname, uname);
        if (IsWindowsVistaOrGreater())    strlen = sprintf_s(strbuf, "%s|%s|WindowsVista", cname, uname);
        if (IsWindowsVistaSP1OrGreater()) strlen = sprintf_s(strbuf, "%s|%s|WindowsVista-SP1", cname, uname);
        if (IsWindowsVistaSP2OrGreater()) strlen = sprintf_s(strbuf, "%s|%s|WindowsVista-SP2", cname, uname);
        if (IsWindows7OrGreater())        strlen = sprintf_s(strbuf, "%s|%s|Windows7", cname, uname);
        if (IsWindows7SP1OrGreater())     strlen = sprintf_s(strbuf, "%s|%s|Windows7-SP1", cname, uname);
        if (IsWindows8OrGreater())        strlen = sprintf_s(strbuf, "%s|%s|Windows8/10", cname, uname);
        if (IsWindows8Point1OrGreater())  strlen = sprintf_s(strbuf, "%s|%s|Windows8.1/10", cname, uname);

        login_buf.push_back((strlen >> 0) & 0xFF);
        login_buf.push_back((strlen >> 8) & 0xFF);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen; i++) login_buf.push_back(strbuf[i]);

        buf = &login_buf[0];
        len = login_buf.size();
```

After everything, `buf` and `len` gets passed to another function that sends the data through the network.

Comment: Can you explain in a few sentences what you mean by "ID" and "unique"? i.e. give a bit of context?

Comment: @einpoklum I'm just trying to have a unique identifier for each application. So I can use it as a session_id when it connects to the server. Just like how a browser uses a cookie.

Comment: What, to you, qualifies as an "identifier"? In what sense it is "unique"? What makes two applications different? And - if what you need is something to use as a session ID, why not just use your process ID? And if you need something like a cookie, why are you always regenerating it?

Comment: @einpoklum I'm only regenerating it when the registry value doesn't exist. If it does I will just use the existing value. 2 applications on the same machine are considered same. The identifier is unique to the machine and not actually the application which is why I used the registry to store the value.

Answer (score 1):

The name `dwUUID` appears to be ill-chosen, as it is bytes rather than double words.

Just after `UuidCreate()`, you populate `dwUUID` first with the style of shifting and masking, then with the style of subscripting. Pick one style and stick with it. Also, it looks like this copy-n-pasted code belongs in a helper function, called by an `if` clause and also by an `else` clause.

When you add os info, you call `sprintf_s()` a great many times in the usual (modern) case. You could replace the `if`s that make that call with `if`s that repeatedly assign `fmt_string`, followed by just a single formatting call.